# Flask view return error "View function did not return a response"

Tags: python, flask

I have a view that calls a function to get the response.  However, it gives the error `View function did not return a response`.  How do I fix this?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

def hello_world():
    return 'test'

@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    hello_world()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try to test it by adding a static value rather than calling the function, it works.

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    return "test"
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The following does not return a response:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    hello_world()
```

You mean to say...

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    return hello_world()
```

Note the addition of `return` in this fixed function.

Answer (score 15):

No matter what code executes in a view function, the view must return [a value that Flask recognizes as a response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#about-responses). If the function doesn't return anything, that's equivalent to returning `None`, which is not a valid response.

In addition to omitting a `return` statement completely, another common error is to only return a response in some cases. If your view has different behavior based on an `if` or a `try`/`except`, you need to ensure that every branch returns a response.

This incorrect example doesn't return a response on GET requests, it needs a return statement after the `if`:

```
@app.route("/hello", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def hello():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return hello_world()

    # missing return statement here
```

This correct example returns a response on success and failure (and logs the failure for debugging):

```
@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    try:
        return database_hello()
    except DatabaseError as e:
        app.logger.exception(e)
        return "Can't say hello."
```

Answer (score 0):

In this error message Flask complains that the `function did not return a valid response`. The emphasis on *response* suggests that it is not just about the function returning a value, but a valid `flask.Response` object which can print a message, return a status code etc. So that trivial example code could be written like this:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    return Response(hello_world(), status=200)
```

Or even better if wrapped in the try-except clause:

```
@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    try:
        result = hello_world()
    except Exception as e:
        return Response('Error: {}'.format(str(e)), status=500)
    return Response(result, status=200)
```