# How to make Flask unit test to test login

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

main.py

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
   username = request.form['username']
   password = request.form['password']
   verify(username, password)


def verify(name, psw):
   data = User.query.filter_by(username=name, password=psw).first()
   if data is not None:
       session['logged_in'] = True
   else:
       session['logged_in'] = False
   return redirect(url_for('home', num=None))
```

test.py

```
class UnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.app = Flask(__name__)
       app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123'
       self.client = self.app.test_client()
       self.app = app.test_client()

   def test_login(self):
       with app.test_client() as client:
           client.post('/login', data=dict(username='s', password='s'))
           with client.session_transaction() as sess:
               assert sess['logged_in']
```

It passes test but there is some error.

[2020-05-25 05:48:58,606] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\queen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\queen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\queen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\queen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to know how to solve the error or how to unit test something?

Comment: This post goes over that error message you're seeing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211942/flask-view-return-error-view-function-did-not-return-a-response