# Flask server internal error, how to fix it

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, jsonify, request
from translate import Translator

en_ge = Translator("geo")
ge_en = Translator("en","geo")

app = Flask("Translator")
@app.route("/send",methods=["GET","POST"])
def send():
    if request.method == "POST":
        word = request.form["word"]
        return render_template("translator.html",word=en_ge.translate(f"{word}"))
    return render_template("index.html")
app.run()
```

I am trying to make translator with flask, but unfortunately I start learning it 10 minutes ago :). I am just trying to win a bet and make it as fast as I can. Googled but I keep receiving server internal error. How to fix it, please help

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Translator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>შეიყვანე სიტყვა</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/send">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="word">
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Translate">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{word}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share error description ?

Comment: [2020-06-20 00:18:09,328] ERROR in app: Exception on /send [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

Comment: this may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211942/flask-view-return-error-view-function-did-not-return-a-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u miss `template_folder` param in Flask object creation, something like

```
app = Flask("Translator", template_folder="full_path_fo_a_folder_where_your_html_is_stored")
```