# Understanding "GET" with Flask and Python

Tags: python, flask, get

I am trying to understand how *GET* works along with Flask and Python.

The following is my `app.py` source code:

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    uname = request.args.get('uname')
    passwrd = request.args.get('pass')
    if uname == "ayush" and passwrd == "google":
        return "Welcome %s" % uname
    else:
        return "Username and password not found!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The following is my `index.html` source code:

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method = "get">
         <table>
        <tr><td>Name</td>
        <td><input type ="text" name ="uname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password</td>
        <td><input type ="password" name ="pass"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type = "submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am not being able to see the login page.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix that?

Comment: You should probably add a `else` statement returning a error, or status code: 401 Not Authenticated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask view return error "View function did not return a response"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211942/flask-view-return-error-view-function-did-not-return-a-response)

Comment: What do you see instead of the login page?

Comment: @mkrieger1, *Username and password not found!*

Comment: This means that `uname == "ayush" and passwrd == "google"` was false.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I intended to first see the login page, then input data, and then allow the Flask to check the input. However, I am unable to get to the login page in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only returning when username and password matches, you need to return something if your `if` condition is not `true`

and you should use `request.form.get` if you are passing form data:

app.py

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    error = None
    uname = request.form.get('uname')
    passwrd = request.form.get('pass')
    if uname is None or passwrd is None:
        error = "Please enter your credentials"
    elif uname == "ayush" and passwrd == "google":
        return "Welcome %s" % uname
    else:
        error = "Invalid creds"

    #Render index.html and pass errors
    return render_template('index.html', error=error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="uname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
        </tr>
        {% if error %}
            <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But, I am not seeing the login page. How can I get to the login page?

Comment: login page means `index.html`?

Comment: Yes. I have only one html page in my current app.